# How to add a view above a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

Hi I wondering how should I go about placing a view such that it cover a entire UINavigationController. Basically I want to add a 0.5 alpha, black overlay to the view to give it a 'disabled' look. And the UINavigationController I'm trying to cover is the DetailViewController of the split view controller on the iPad.

I know I can add the view as a subview to the navigation controllers root view but that won't cover the navigation bar at the top.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As i understand you want to cover all the screen with your view. May be this will help

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:coverView];
```

Comment: That definitely did it. Thanks!

Comment: This will only cover rootviewcontroller's view.
Not NavihgationBar.
I need the same thing but i i want it cover UIVavigationBar As well. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

I also tried the marked answer, but it didn't work for me. I found another solution which was simple and did it:

#### Insert Appdelegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

#### Get Delegate, cast and add subview to main window

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.window addSubview:alertVC.view];
```